# ReactJS map() onMouseEnter add css to specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

I'm displaying my data using the map function, and I want to add CSS style to for specific index when the mouse enters in the div, but when I tried to hover the div, all data list showing the same style at the same time.
Can someone help me with this concern?

[image]

Here is the code

```
     const [view, setView] = useState(false);
      const Show = (index) => {
        setView(true);
        alert(index);
      };
     const Hide = (index) => {
      setView(false);
     };
     {data.map((res, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
           <div
            className={classes.blogCard}
            onMouseEnter={() => Show(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => Hide(index)}
           >   
              <h1>{res.title}</h1>   
             <div
               className={
                            view
                            ? classes.blogLink + " " + classes.hoverLink
                            : classes.blogLink
                         }
             >
             <h5 className={classes.blogListTitlle}>{res.title}</h5>

              {view ? <p className={classes.text}>{res.desciption}</p> :false }                 
                        
            </div>
          </div>
     ))}
```

Comment: If you are able, can you share the entire component? I think this may need a little more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution below. It's best if you split this into 2 components: one is the articles container and the article component itself. Control the addition of extra CSS styles by adding or removing the `view` class. In your CSS code add all the extra styles in this class.

```
const data = [{ title: 'Article 1' }, { title: 'Article 2' }, { title: 'Article 3' }];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((res, index) => (
        <Article key={index} title={res.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const Article = ({ title }) => {
  const [view, setView] = React.useState('');
  const handleMouseEnter = () => setView('view');
  const handleMouseLeave = () => setView('');
  return (
    <div className={`some-class-name ${view}`} 
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} 
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @M.Calugaru, Thank you for your help it works!